# Google OAuth2 Error - Installation Failure Message about Security Policy

Tags: google-chrome, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-apps

At around 9:30 PST yesterday (10/2), several users reported errors with the following text:

```
Error: policy_enforced

Application: *****

You can email the developer of this application at:*****

Access denied by a security policy established by the Google Apps administrator of your organization. Please contact your administrator for further assistance

Details:
response_type=code
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ https://mail.google.com/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.userhttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license
redirect_uri=*****
login_hint=*****
state=pw_signin|||*****
hd=*****
client_id=*****
That’s all we know.
```

Our application hasn't changed since Tuesday (9/30).  We are still using the following deprecated scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

We aren't convinced that changing them to the new scopes will help though.  Has anyone discovered what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If this just started happening last night, this is occurring due to an update Google pushed which they are in the process of rolling back. The following was posted on G+:

> Apologies for the issue, this was caused by a change we made today.
>   We're going to rollback tomorrow so that this issue will be resolved.
>   In the meantime, you can also fix the issue with a code change as
>   well:
>
> The root cause is a mismatch between the authorized scopes and
>   what you're requesting at login time. In the GAM settings, the
>   deprecated scopes are being used (hardcoded, this is our fault):
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
>
> In the request, you're likely using the newer scopes:
>
> email
>
> profile
>
> Semantically, these are the same scopes. However, the scopes aren't normalized and
>   are just compared directly. Before today, if there was a mismatch it
>   would fall back to the behavior of prompting the user to grant the
>   additional scopes. Earlier today a change was pushed that tightened
>   the policy.
>
> The quickest fix is to revert back to the
>   userinfo.profile and/or userinfo.email scopes in your login requests.
>   That shouldn't require admins to take any action and should restore
>   login functionality.
>
> Alternately, you can add the email & profile
>   scopes to your SDK settings and have admins reauthorize. Long term
>   that has the benefit of getting you off the deprecated scopes and will
>   allow you to remove them once that's allowed in the developer console.

Comment: Where did you find that G+ post? Is it a private group we have to join?

Comment: I believe it was up in the Developing Enterprise Apps with Google G+ Community (https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/116649587096405255956?cfem=1).